# Vim autocomplete to store words between documents

Tags: autocompletion

### User statement:

I use Vim to write many technical text documents, including emails.

### Question:

Is it possible to "store unique words" from past documents in some `.vim/file` that would be automatically loaded when any future file is opened and the  `Ctrl+N` command is issued? I know others have asked about pointing to a dictionary file in addition to the current file (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20887628/vim-auto-complete-both-with-current-file-and-dictionary) but I'd rather the process was dynamic.

### Ideal behavior:

I'd like to write one email containing `Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious`. Then, in some future email, I'd like to start writing `Superc` and then `Ctrl+N` would complete the word.

### Further thoughts/requests:

1. I assume there is concern about such a "carryover file" growing excessively large over time. It would be great if it is possible to prevent "words shorter than `K` characters" from being stored.
2. I'm also willing/interested in manually editing such a file.

Comment: It seems as if you mean by "dynamic" some sort of "vim knows which words I want to add and which I don't" thing. If that's the case, I don't think it's possible. It is, however, possible to add unrecognized-but-correctly-spelled words to a separate dictionary, https://superuser.com/questions/133208/how-to-make-vim-spellcheck-remember-a-new-word

Comment: Dictionaries are good, as @MDeBusk suggests. But you can also write your own completion (`:help compl-function`) that might, for example, using `readfile()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the best you can do in this regard is to build a custom dictionary manually and include those new words as part of the matches for Insert mode completion.

In your runtime user directory, create a new directory called `spell` and in your `.vimrc`, add the following lines:

```
set spell
set spellfile=~/.vim/spell/vim-spell-en.utf-8.add
set complete+=kspell
```

You may want to read :h 'spellfile' and :h spell-load, but basically, vim will store your "custom" words in the path set by `spellfile` (this file must end in `.{encoding}.add`). If you only want to use this custom dictionary for a single language, add a prefix for the language as shown above (`{language}.{encoding}.add`).

After adding your words (with `zg`), run `set spell`, type the first letters of your word and press `Ctrl+N` and you word will be among the suggestions in the pop-up menu.

On your additional requests:

1 - That should be possible by calling a function that

- List all the words in a buffer (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48024588/460147)
- Filter such words based on your condition (:h filter())
- Loop over those words with `execute ':spellgood! ' . word`

2 - Unfortunately, you cannot manually change this dictionary since this procedure results in a binary file.

Comment: Regarding point 2 above: (For me) the file `~/.vim/spell/vim-spell-en.utf-8.add` is stored in plain text and can be edited.

Comment: @jmlarson Yes, but that's not the file vim uses for autocompletion.

Comment: By the way, I didn't add `set spell` because I often enable spelling manually, but if you work with text files for which autocomplete is a must-have or spelling is often used, then it is certainly a good idea to enable it by default.